# How to start java process if it die from script

Tags: linux, bash

I have bash script to start java process using below command:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar test.jar
```

I want to make a script so that if the java process of this jar die it will start again from this script. Do i need a do while loop in my script and what condition should i use to check that is java process of this jar is running or not and if die then fire it up again.

Comment: Search for `exit status of the script`!

Comment: `while ! java -jar test.jar; do :; done` Will run until `test.jar` exits with 0 as exit status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will run until `test.jar` exits with 0 as exit code

```
while ! java -jar test.jar; do :; done
```

Breakdown:

```
while ! java -jar test.jar; do :; done
#     ^ ^                      ^
#     | |                      while loops needs a body, and `:` will do nothing
#     | The command to run, while will check the exit code and continue if its 0 (true) 
#     Flip the exit code, so true becomes false and false becomes true
```

If you are interested to run until `test.jar` exits will falsy exit code, you can omit the `!`:

```
while java -jar test.jar; do :; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `bash` until in a loop until the bash success return code `0` is seen.

```
#!/bin/bash
until java -jar test.jar
do
   echo "Retrying Command.."
done
```